# Laravel is ignoring $primarykey as model's primary key

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

Even this seems to be frequently asked question, it's driving me crazy.

I have this model:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'product';
    protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';
}
```

When I try to get the data from the mode, for example like this:

```
Product::find(29);
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'product.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `product` where `product`.`id` = 29 limit 1)
```

Why is Laravel still thinks my primary key is the default 'id', while I have specifically set it otherwise? Is there any cache to clear for Models, or am I missing something?

Comment: What id the **data type** of 'product_id' in your table?

Comment: it's "product_id". Anyway, I had to rename it to "id" just to make it work.